# Attaching javadoc for external libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way of **linking javadoc to libraries in AndroidStudio**? I'm using the June `18 dev build of Android Studio`, and my dependency for the android plugin is: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3`.`Gradle 2.4` is being used by the wrapper.

If, for example, I delete everything from `~/.gradle/caches` and rebuild project then all libraries are downloaded. I resynch in `AS` and then by `navigating eg`. to class `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert` AS allows me to `download` or `choose sources`. That gets me to sourcecode (as opposed to dissassembled code), but how to get linked external javadoc. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220